# How to add list in file to Lisp

Tags: list, file-io, lisp, common-lisp

I want to add list in text file to lisp and bound it to some variable.
For example 
     Mylist.txt contains:
           ((1 2 3 4)
            (5 6 7 8)
            (9 10 11 12)
            (13 14 15 16)
           )
And i want to read from this file and and set this list to some variable mylist.

```
    (defun readfile (fileName) (let ((in (open fileName :if-does-not-exist nil)))
     (when in
       (loop for line = (read in nil)

       while line do (print line))
       (close in)
      )
     ) )


   (setf myList (readfile "list.txt"))
```

Output should be (myList should be bounded to): 
           ((1 2 3 4)
            (5 6 7 8)
            (9 10 11 12)
            (13 14 15 16)
           )

I have seen most of the answer on stackflow regarding this, But non them worked for example i tried reading it line by line and used collect but that dont seem to give me right answer since it collect's the entire line and treat it as list item.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Are you trying to read the data from the file and you want a string? or do you want a list? I thought you wanted a list but your last sentence implies you do *not* want a list. Also your code above does not read line by line, it reads an expression.

Comment: sorry about being vague. I am trying to read LIST from file assuming the file has list without any error. for example list.txt file should contain
((R DR DL L)
(DR L O DL)
(DR UR UR U)
(R UR U G))
And i want to set this values in array-list or list. Let me know if you still have questions regarding this. And as far as my code goes, I know i am reading it as string because i dont know how to read file as whole.

Comment: If you just want to read a list that is the first thing in the file, simply calling `read` once should do the job. No need to loop. You should use `with-open-file` instead of manually opening and closing the file.

Comment: @jkiiski it worked. But i am getting
((RÂ DR DLÂ L) (DRÂ LÂ OÂ DL) (DRÂ URÂ URÂ U) (RÂ URÂ UÂ G))
I have only one space between items. I dont know what "Â" came from. Can you please tell me how can i get rid of that.

Original Text file contained:
((R DR DL L)
(DR L O DL)
(DR UR UR U)
(R UR U G))

Comment: I guess that's a character encoding problem. Try typing it by hand to another file. If that doesn't solve it, try switching the character encoding to ASCII or utf-8 in your text editor.

Comment: awesome. it worked. I had copied it from some where else thats why it was not working. But it is working now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As it stands so far you are reading the file and printing it to standard output (`(print line)` statement in `READFILE`). Instead, you want to collect the input.

```
(defun read-file (file-name)
  (let ((*read-eval* nil))
   (with-open-file (in file-name)
     (loop for x = #1=(read-line in nil :eof) then #1#
        until (eq x :eof)
        collect (read-from-string x)))))
```

Line-by-line:
1. Please, use CL conventions for names.
2. Reading from string/file is dangerous in the presence of [read macros](http://letoverlambda.com/index.cl/guest/chap4.html). Setting `*READ-EVAL*` to `NIL` prevents their execution.
3. The reading we need to do is simple. Using `WITH-OPEN-FILE` provides a simple and safe interface (e.g. if a condition (exception) is raised, it will close the file properly). `IN` is a name of the input stream associated with the file.
4. In the `LOOP` at each iteration read one line. Here I assume that each line is a proper Lisp expression (e.g., a number or a list). If you have the expression spanning multiple lines, this needs to be changed. `#1=` lets you remember the form that follows it and `#1#` insert that form. This is used to avoid repetition of `(READ-LINE ...)` form for initial and *then* statements. The `READ-LINE` is directed not to throw an error if the end-of-file is reached and return `:EOF` instead.
5. Until end-of-file is reached...
6. Read (convert from string to a Lisp data) and collect the line read from file.

This function returns the list of (read into Lisp data) lines of file. For example, if "text.txt" contains

```
((1 2 3) (4 5 6))
(a b c)
(:f :g :h)
```

The `READ-FILE` of "test.txt" will result in:

```
CL-USER> (read-file "test.txt")
(((1 2 3) (4 5 6)) (A B C) (:F :G :H))
```

Finally, do not use `SETF` unless `MY-LIST` is defined using `DEFVAR` or `DEFPARAMETER` (in which case it should be named `*MY-LIST*`) or if it is defined locally using `LET`.